# How could I create an AutoSequence in a private testnet with the golang SDK?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, go-sdk

With the DefaultTestNetClient implementing the SequenceProvider interface, when we use a private testnet, how would we need to implement this since without it (I guess) transactions cannot be submitted to stellar-core ? I am not using the DefaultTestNetClient and have used my own created from [horizon.Client](https://godoc.org/github.com/stellar/go/clients/horizon#Client). So, I either have to write my own SequenceProvider or use [SequenceForAccount](https://godoc.org/github.com/stellar/go/clients/horizon#Client.SequenceForAccount).
Or can I do away with having the transaction sequence auto generated ?

My primary use case is that I am trying to create a new transaction and submit it in Stellar private testnet.

Please correct me where needed.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that I needed to implement my own SequenceProvider looking at https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/clients/horizon/main.go#L20 and https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/clients/horizon/main.go#L108 and https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/clients/horizon/main.go#L111